Schefflera dying

This is my first time owning a plant and I am trying my best but it seems to be dying :((
I was told to water it whenever the soil is very dry, two fingers deep, so I ended up watering it about once a month. Unfortunately one of the main branches completely died so I had to remove that one. However, there is another one that seems half brown and I’m not sure what to do about it.
Also confused as to what I’m doing wrong… :(((
Can anyone help me?

Hi Audrey, we'd love to help you.  Could you please take a picture of the plant?

You're treating a tropical plant like it's a desert plant?

This plant has major problems.  The brown part of the stem is dead and it should be cut back until you see live tissue.
The other problem is that the other stems have sunken areas along the stem indicating it has been kept too dry.
You should:

move to an area with higher light
expect to have more leaves drop
water more often, at least every two weeks water until it runs out of the bottom of the pot and then leave to dry

If it doesn't perk up you could cut the stems back to a few inches above the soil or just move it along as it is likely it will be a long time until it looks nice again.
